# Convert string to scancodes for pyvbox

Tags: python, keyboard, virtualbox, scancodes

I'm trying to use pyvbox to enter some text into a virtual machine, but it takes keyboard input as a list of keyboard scancodes. I'd like to convert a regular Python string into a list of scancodes.

I'm aware that I could probably brute force it by trying each scancode and seeing what I get, but I wondered if there's a library or similar out there. AFAIK, scancodes are keyboard layout dependant, so it would presumably need to be configured with a keyboard layout.

Comment: There seem to be a scancode dictionary already defined inside the [source code](https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/8562/pyvbox/virtualbox/library_ext/keyboard.py/)
And if you wish to see the codes, you may use [xev](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) if you are on linux and try out various  keys.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun So there is. If you post that as an answer you can have the bounty.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted it as an answer.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun I have to wait 22 hours before I can give the bounty. I'll give it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a scancode dictionary already defined inside the [source code](https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/8562/pyvbox/virtualbox/library_ext/keyboard.py/) And if you wish to see the codes, you may use [xev](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) if you are on linux and try out various keys.